# Preventing href statements from underlining your text button

Tags: css, underline

Right now I am attempting to prevent a text button from underlining itself. This button is located in a table which is why I have a `<td>` tag. However when apply internal style to rid of the underlining, it remains underlined. How can I get rid of this, or am I incorrectly getting rid of this. I learned how to disable the underline from here: http://www.pageresource.com/html/link3.htm  But like I said before, it failed.

```
  <td style="text-decoration:none"><a href="view_topic.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['subject']; ?> </a><BR></td>
```

Comment: You should consider not using inline styles. To get the same result without inline styles, add a class to your anchor tag, and put text-decoration: none; on that class in the CSS file associated with your page.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely must have your styles inline, then in this case you need the `text-decoration:none` applied in the style attribute of the anchor, rather then the table cell:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="view_topic.php?id=<?php...
```

Doing it this way though, you have to apply it to every element, rather than using a css class to apply it to all links at once.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've placed the text-decoration styling on the `td` instead of the `a`

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the text-decoration to the `a` element, not the table cell.

```
<td>
    <a style="text-decoration:none" href="view_topic.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $rows['subject']; ?>     
    </a><BR>
</td>
```

Here is a fiddle showing the difference between the two: http://jsfiddle.net/LsFK5/

Answer (score 0):

just change your code to

```
<td><a style="text-decoration:none !important;" href="view_topic.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['subject']; ?> </a><BR></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the style from the td tag to the anchor tag.

```
<td><a href="view_topic.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" style="text-decoration:none"><?php echo $rows['subject']; ?> </a><BR></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class to your `<a>` element such as `.a-no-underline` and then in your CSS file, you can add a style rule such as:

```
.a-no-underline {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Make sure that you apply this class to the `<a>` element and not the `<td>` element. Like so:

```
<td>
    <a class="a-no-underline" href="view_topic.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $rows['subject']; ?> 
    </a><br/>
</td>
```